# I like to prove sum of new discrete random variable`s pmf is equal 1

Tags: probability-distributions

First of all from last question I can obtain some discrete random variable which described below. In this page, we denote this random variable as $Z$.

$P(Z=0) = e^{-\lambda}+(1-e^{-\lambda})(1-\beta)$
$P(Z=n\beta) = \frac{\lambda^{n}}{n!}e^{-\lambda}\beta,   (n>0)$
$\beta$ is constant which is lower than 1.

And there is Poisson random variable X with $T\lambda$

$P(n;T\lambda)=\frac{(T\lambda)^{n}}{n!}e^{-T\lambda}$

I made new random variable $K=X+Z$ and i like to know distribution of $T$.
Because sum of two random variable`s distribution is formed by convolution of two random variable, i made below equation.
$P(K=k)=\sum_{z}P(X=k-z)P(Z=z)$

And using this equation i can obtain pmf like below

$P(K=0)=\sum_{z}P(X=-z)P(Z=z)=P(X=0)P(Z=0)=e^{-T\lambda}(e^{-\lambda}+(1-e^{-\lambda})(1-\beta))$
$P(K=k)=\sum^{k}_{z}P(X=k-z)P(Z=z)=\sum^{k}_{z}\frac{(T\lambda)^{k-z}}{(k-z)!}e^{-T\lambda}\frac{\lambda^{z/\beta}}{(z/\beta)!}e^{-\lambda}\beta$
($z=n\beta$ from above $Z$)

I tried to check $P(K=0)+\sum P(K=k)$ is $1$.
But it is not easy to me.

Is there anyone who can help me?
If there are some miss approach, please let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: Please learn to format your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you. It is very help to me

Comment: Unless I misunderstand, it seems $Z$ is not an integer but takes values $0,\beta,2\beta,\ldots$. So $K$ is not an integer and you can't make a convolution of $X$ and $Z$.